# Laravel 5.6 inRandomOrder and OrderBy

Tags: php, laravel

How to take datas from Database like this. But randomly and never duplicate.

```
$questions = Question::orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->skip(0)->take(3)->get();
$inquiries = Question::orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->skip(3)->take(3)->get();
$queries = Question::orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->skip(6)->take(3)->get();
$examinations = Question::orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->skip(9)->take(3)->get();
$inquisitions = Question::orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->skip(12)->take(3)->get();
```

It works but duplicates.

```
$questions = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$inquiries = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$queries = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$examinations = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$inquisitions = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about you get them all with 1 call and sort them with PHP using collection [splice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-splice) method:

```
$all = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(50)->get();

$questions = $all->splice(0, 10);
$inquiries = $all->splice(0, 10);
$queries = $all->splice(0, 10);
$examinations = $all->splice(0, 10);
$inquisitions = $all->splice(0, 10);
```

You could also just save IDs you've already pulled in an array and ignore those when doing new queries with `->whereNotIn()` like this:

```
$except = []; // We'll save IDs of those pulled already here

$questions = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $questions->pluck('id')->toArray()); // Add IDs from upper call

// Add ->whereNotIn, to ignore IDs from $except
$inquiries = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get(); 
$except = array_merge($except, $inquiries->pluck('id')->toArray()); // Add IDs from upper call

$queries = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $queries->pluck('id')->toArray()); // Add IDs from upper call

$examinations = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();
$except = array_merge($except, $examinations->pluck('id')->toArray()); // Add IDs from upper call

$inquisitions = Question::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id', $except)->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Oh yeah, you have to call `->toArray()` after `->pluck()` as well. But I strongly recommend first method as you'll only make 1 SQL call instead of 5. Edited my answer to include `->toArray()`

Comment: Oh god. Thanks for your help and knowledge sir. I was looking for it.